# ireport Connot show htmlcomponent like <input type="checkbox"/>

Tags: html, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I use the IReport to create PDF file. I also use html component in IReport.
But same html element connot show like this

```
<input type ="checkbox"/>
```

The html element can show normally like this

```
<label> Hello Word</label>
```

How to show the checkbox-element by html component in iReport?

[image: How I add the html component and set the value]

Comment: JasperReports' html component does not support all features of *html*. Do you need interactive checkbox? If no, you can use image for example

Comment: @AlexK  How to user image to show checkbox? thanks a lot for your answer. Is using the checkbox icon to replace  html-checkbox and to create an image ?